# switching between css sheets according to screen width not working in IE7

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following which is not working in IE7.

```
<!-- styles to use for small screens, such as phones -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" href="phone.css">

<!-- styles to use for medium screens, such as tablets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:800px)" href="tablet.css">

<!-- styles to use for larger screens, such as desktops and laptops -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:801px)" href="styles.css">
```

I would like to know why this doesn't work in IE7?
Is there a way to do this all in one style sheet...that will work in IE?

Thanks

I ended up doing it this way so that it drives IE8 (and below) directly to my standard style sheet:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!-- styles to use for small screens, such as phones -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" href="phone.css">

<!-- styles to use for medium screens, such as tablets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:800px)" href="tablet.css">

<!-- styles to use for larger screens, such as desktops and laptops -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:801px)" href="styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set parts of you css code to be browser-specific.

**[This page](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)** contains information on how to do this!

Comment: thanks, this was a great link

Answer (score 0):

I think your 'code' did not paste properly.

Also, I assume you are trying to use media queries with IE. IE does not support media queries and won't read them. It will basically skip them.

Now, you could use a library like respond.js. From its description:

"A fast & lightweight polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries (for IE 6-8, and more)"
[Respond.js page](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)